# How to play video when there is no action perform on screen for 5 mins in Android?

Tags: android, user-interaction

I want when my app exit, after exit if there is no action perform on screen for 5 minutes a video will play every time, this video id define in my app.
Any help would be appreciated. Thankx in advance.

I have the following class but it is not worked fine, how can make the same code as Services ?

```
public class IdlePhoneState extends Activity {

Handler hl_timeout = new Handler();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{
        hl_timeout.postDelayed(DoOnTimeOut, 120000); // 2 min
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

//  Toast
Thread DoOnTimeOut = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "System is idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onUserInteraction()
{
    super.onUserInteraction();
    //Remove any previous callback
    try{
    hl_timeout.removeCallbacks(DoOnTimeOut);
    hl_timeout.postDelayed(DoOnTimeOut, 120000);

    System.out.println("ggggggggggggggggggggg");
    Intent intr= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoPlayerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intr);


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Explain exactly what you're looking for! Something like **live wallpaper**?

Comment: You can use Service for it which will play your video in background.

Comment: i want something like screen saver

Comment: In a service, how can i check that any action perform on screen from last 5 min or not ??

Comment: @Khushboo There for there is Count down timer or TimerTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like below.

1. you should set an id on the outer-most element of your layout:

   android:id="@+id/entire_view"
2. In java file find it like below.

   View view = getViewById(R.id.entire_view);
3. Write touchlistener code for that root layout.

view.setOnTouchListener( ...
in the touch save the touched time to shared prefereces are something like that. Then compare the saved time with current time. if the difference exceeds five mins then play the video.

For time duration checking try to use Alarm Manager else use CountDownTimer.

Comment: I think this is very lengthy...can u tell me some other way like through services or broadcast receiver

Comment: the method OnUserInteraction(), what and where should i define it ?

Comment: setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

Comment: Whats mean by action here? it includes touches also right ? If yes then we have to do in this way only. There is nothing lengthy I hope . Just you have to manage one CountDownTimer thats it

Comment: But can you tell me how can i make service of the above code

Comment: Same behaviour.. you have to manage it starting and stopping the service. if touched the screen stop and start the service with next 5 mins.

Comment: can we intent an Activity in Services ?